# Django and authomatic: ImportError: cannot import name 'six'

Tags: django

Here are the steps I've made:

- cd `[mydjangoproject]`
- `git clone git://github.com/peterhudec/authomatic.git`
- Into my views, just added this line: `from authomatic import authomatic`

My djangoproject tree looks like:

```
├── authomatic
│   ├── assets
│   ├── authomatic
│   ├── doc
│   ├── examples
│   ├── javascript
│   └── tests
├── locale
│   ├── en
│   ├── fr
│   └── sv
├── produits
│   ├── migrations
│   └── templatetags
├── pyweb
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── images
│   ├── js
│   └── produits
└── templates
    └── produits
```

The problem appears in the `[mydjangoproject]/authomatic/authomatic/__init__.py`, line 21, where it's this code:

```
from . import six
```

Of course I've double-checked that the file exists:

```
>cd [mydjangoproject]/authomatic/authomatic/
>find .
.
./adapters.py
./core.py
./exceptions.py
...blabla...
./six.py
./__init__.py
```

And what is strange is that with Pycharm, if I ctrl-click on the `six` of the sentence `from . import six` in the file `__init__.py`, Pycharm finds it and displays the `six.py` file...

It should work I guess... Any idea what's going on?

Comment: wouldn't it be, `from authomatic import six` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but I've added all the path manually in the `settings.py` file like this:

```
sys.path.append('./third_party/defusedxml-0.4.1')
sys.path.append('./third_party/python3-openid')
sys.path.append('./third_party/authomatic_0_1_0')
```

And it seems to work. Now I'm facing the fact that google app engine doesnt support Python 3, which is something I dont understand for a company that claims to embody "state-of-the-art technologies".